# Would this sequence cause 'master' to be merged into branch 'A'?

Tags: git

I have any issue where master is getting merged into a branch 'releasebranch1'.

The scenario is as follows.

Most of the team are working on the release branch: 'releasebranch1'.
Occasionally a bug fix is made which needs to to copied to 'master'. So we do this:

1. commit the fix to releasebranch1.
2. checkout master, then 'git cherry-pick xxxx'
3. Then 'git push origin master' to merge the cherry-pick to remote.

How what if - whilst master is checked out - so current branch is master, and this is executed:

'git push origin *releasebranch1*' rather than 'git push origin *master*'

Would that merge master into releasebranch1?

That is what seems to be happening (unless I'm mistaken).
The only other thing that *could* be happening, is that someone is executing :

git merge master

when they shouldn't be. The symptoms I am seeing is that master code is ending up in the branch when it should not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git push origin releasebranch1` will take your current branch and push changes to the remote `origin/releasebranch1`.  Git will take your changes that are on `master` and try to update `origin/releasebranch1` with what it can.  This won't result in a merge commit but will cause commits on master to now be on the remote branch available for other people to pull.  You can push any local branch to any remote.

To avoid this problem, set the your branches to track the proper remote and all you would need to do is `git push` and you don't have to worry about people accidentally pushing data to the wrong branch.

To set up the tracking (if it isn't already): `git push -u origin <branchname>` being on the branch that you want.  You can see the branches that your local branches are tracking via `git branch -vv`.

Comment: `origin/releasebranch1` is not a remote, but a remote tracking branch. The remote is called `origin`. And git will refuse the push if there are any commits on `releasebranch1` on the remote that are not on master.

Comment: Git will stop the push if the commits have diverged and a merge is required. But if the head of the remote is in the local branch the push will update the remote branch with the subsequent commits updating it.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I've described.

Comment: Except that the OP's issue cannot only be caused by merging, it can happen via push.

Answer (score 1):

No, git push can never create a merge commit, merges *always* happen locally.

So this can only be caused by someone merging master while they are on releasebranch1.